# Calling a function from same class

Tags: python

I'm using the following class as an simplified example of what i have. So, how can i call the function beta from alfa without receiving  the error : NameError: global name 'beta' is not defined

```
class Test:
    def alfa(self):
        beta('a')
    def beta(something):
        print " what i get:"+something
call=Test()
call.alfa()
```

Should i use `global beta` after the class declaration? It works if i do it,  but i'm not sure if is the correct way to do.

Regards.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, im reading the python docs but im still at the beginning.

Comment: Basically, you need to pass self as the first parameter for any instance method. It need not be called 'self' though. It's just a convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.beta()`.

And beta should take `self` as a parameter, exactly the same as `alpha` does.